# Error C2535: 'ManagedArray::ManagedArray(void)'

Tags: c++

I was working on a project and after multiple searches for the error in the title I am pretty much lost. If I may please get some help figuring this out.

```
class ManagedArray
{

    public:

     float *elements;
     int numberOfElements; 

     /* default constructor */
     ManagedArray() :elements(NULL){};
     ManagedArray() :numberOfElements(0){}; <--Where the error is

     /*accessor*/
     int size() {return numberOfElements; }
     float get(int index) {return elements[index]; }
```

Comment: Redefinition of the constructor, perhaps? You should have one, which initializes both members. And I bet that your title isn't the full error message.

Comment: Which of those two constructors would you expect to be called? There can only sensibly be one default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (9.2 Class members)

> 1. ...**A member shall not be declared twice in the member-specification**, except that a nested class or member class
>      template can be declared and then later defined, and except that an
>      enumeration can be introduced with an opaque-enum-declaration and
>      later redeclared with an enum-specifier.

You declared and defined the default constructor  two times

```
 ManagedArray() :elements(NULL){};
 ManagedArray() :numberOfElements(0){}; <--Where the error is
```

You could add a parameter to the second constructor as for example

```
 ManagedArray() :elements(NULL){};
 ManagedArray( int n ) :numberOfElements(n){};
```

or the following way

```
 explicit ManagedArray( int n ) :numberOfElements(n){};
 ^^^^^^^^
```

Take into account that instead of type `int` it is better to use type `size_t` for data member `numberOfElements` at least because the number of elements can not be negative.

Also the both constructors should initialize all data members.

For example

```
 ManagedArray() :elements(NULL), numberOfElements( 0 ){};
```

Comment: @TarenDay We, beginners, should help each other.:)